# Labels getting y position set to inf

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbar

When transitioning to a new view controller with my tab bar controller, one on of the tabs I want to hide the tab bar controller. To accomplish this, I use the following code:

```
- (CGFloat)tabBarHeight {
    if (self.isTabBarHidden) {
        return 0;
    }
    return TAB_BAR_HEIGHT;
}

- (void)shouldHideTabBar:(BOOL)hideTabBar {
    self.isTabBarHidden = hideTabBar;
    self.tabBarHeightConstraint.constant = [self tabBarHeight];
    self.tabBar.hidden = hideTabBar;
    self.bottomBorder.hidden = hideTabBar;
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

I call `shouldHideTabBar:` as necessary with the appropriate BOOL. However, when setting the constant on the `tabBarHeightConstraint` to 0, the labels y position gets set to `inf`. This causes all sorts of issues when I try to do some blurring and animations.

Does anyone know why my labels are flying off to infinity when I set the constraint to zero? Anything I should check elsewhere in the app, or is this some weird behavior of a TabBar?

Comment: Bill, what's wrong with my answer? If you don't understand, it is standard method from UIKit to hide tabbar through push transition.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe better approach is to use method:

```
-(BOOL)hidesBottomBarWhenPushed {
    return YES;
}
```

inside view controller on which you would hide tabbar?